# Change a button when empty or another value in list with AJAX Select2

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to understand who work the AJAX Select2

I have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
                    <button id="importerAffaire" type="submit" >Importer</button>

</form>
```

So, What I want, when I put a another value in the list, I want to display another button:

```
<button id="creerAffaire" type="submit" >Create</button>
```

And the most important it's to take into account the new value in the list or another way because what I want, it's if the value doesn't exist need to push into database.

So can you explain me the best way ? thank you

Comment: I think `.select2()` is made to search through the select options, not to insert new options.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  What specifically have you tried and what specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: @CesarePolonara https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items. This link maybe give your more information

Comment: @David In other word, I need to insert new value in dropdown and display the button create and not import

Comment: @jeremy: And what have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  For example, to insert a new value in the dropdown, the plugin vendor [has documentation for that](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items).  You are encouraged to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to make it possible to add a new entry to the select, and in case a new entry is added, to send it to your backend through AJAX, so you can update your options values in DB.
Following `select2` documentation:
https://select2.org/tagging

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    tags: true,
    createTag: createEntry
  });
  $("form").submit((e) => e.preventDefault())
  $("select").change(handleSubmit)
});

function createEntry(params) {
  const term = $.trim(params.term);

  if (term === '') {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    id: term,
    text: term,
    newTag: true // add additional parameters
  }
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  console.log("SUBMITTING VALUE", e.target.value)
  // SEND THE SELECTED OPTION TO YOUR BACKEND, THERE YOU PERFORM THE CHECK IF THE SELECTED VALUE IS A NEW VALUE OR NOT
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</form>
```